# Split 16 digit string into 4 parts and store them in an array in C#

Tags: c#, string, variables, split

I have a string composed of 16 digits (a hexadecimal number), which will be entered in a textbox as one large number.  For example, '1111222233334444".

I need to

- read this number in,
- divide it into four groups, such as 1111 2222 3333 4444.
- store the groups into four variables, or an array

I have found some methods to do this, but they just write to console.  So after the user enters that data, I need to have something like:

```
    string first = 1111; 
    string second = 2222; 
    string third = 3333; 
    string fourth = 4444.
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Um, call `Substring` four times? (Look at `String.Substring(int, int)`...)

Comment: Looks like that's all I needed.  Figured it'd be simple, lol.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm sure someone can find an incomprehensible solution using Linq :)

Comment: @JonB: `var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => str.Substring(i *4, 4)).ToArray()` :)

Comment: @JonB Sure, just convert it to a char array and then use `.Take()`!  Simple and efficient.  Except for the part where you'd never do this.

Comment: dasblinkenlight sees your Linq and raises with Regex.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with substring.

```
string strNumber = "1111222233334444";

string []strArr = new string[4];

for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
{
   strArr[i] = strNumber.Substring(i*4, 4);
}
```

Comment: Man you guys are quick.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here it is:

```
string initial_string = TextBox1.Text;  //read from textbox 

string [] number = new string[4];

number[0] = initial_string.Substring(0,4);
number[1] = initial_string.Substring(4,4);
number[2] = initial_string.Substring(8,4);
number[3] = initial_string.Substring(12,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex to do it in a single line:

```
var res = Regex.Split(str, "(?<=\\G\\d{4})");
```

**NOTE:** This works fine under Microsoft .NET, but does not work with Mono's implementation of Regex.